# Oracle inbuilt function connect_by_isleaf conversion to BQ issue

Tags: google-bigquery

We are working on the BQ migration project.

**In one scenario we use the Oracle function to find the extreme most parent_order**

```
 FUNCTION get_do_id (p_order_id t501_order.c501_order_id%TYPE)
      RETURN VARCHAR2
   IS
      v_do_id   t501_order.c501_order_id%TYPE;
   BEGIN
      BEGIN
         SELECT orderlist.order_id
           INTO v_do_id
           FROM (SELECT t501.c501_order_id order_id, connect_by_isleaf leaf
                   FROM t501_order t501
                     START WITH t501.c501_order_id = p_order_id CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR t501.c501_parent_order_id = t501.c501_order_id) orderlist
          WHERE orderlist.leaf = 1;
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
         THEN
            RETURN NULL;
      END;
```

There is no similar function in BQ.

I tried using the With Recursive in BQ. The main problem is not able to be added inside the function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `BQ_GMED_OTC.get_do_id`(p_order_id STRING) RETURNS STRING AS (
(
  WITH RECURSIVE ParentorderHierarchy AS (
  SELECT c501_order_id AS order_id, c501_parent_order_id AS parent_id, 1 AS level
  FROM `BQ_GMED_RAW.T501_ORDER`
  WHERE c501_order_id = p_order_id

  UNION ALL

  SELECT t.c501_order_id, t.c501_parent_order_id, level + 1
  FROM `BQ_GMED_RAW.T501_ORDER` t
  JOIN ParentorderHierarchy ON t.c501_order_id = ParentorderHierarchy.parent_id
)

select order_id from (
SELECT order_id, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT(parent_id) OVER (PARTITION BY order_id) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS leaf_value
FROM ParentorderHierarchy
ORDER BY level) where leaf_value = 1
)
);
```

**Error**:

> WITH RECURSIVE is only allowed at the top level of the SELECT, CREATE
> TABLE AS SELECT, CREATE VIEW, INSERT, EXPORT DATA statements.

I also tried the Stored Procedure approach.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `BQ_GMED_RAW.get_do_id_new`(p_order_id STRING)
BEGIN
  DECLARE done BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE current_order_id STRING;

WITH RECURSIVE OrderHierarchy AS (
    SELECT org.c501_order_id AS order_id, c501_parent_order_id AS parent_id, 1 AS level, org.c501_order_id AS org_order_id
    FROM `BQ_GMED_RAW.T501_ORDER` org
    WHERE c501_order_id = p_order_id 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.c501_order_id, t.c501_parent_order_id, level + 1, OrderHierarchy.org_order_id
    FROM `BQ_GMED_RAW.T501_ORDER` t
    JOIN OrderHierarchy ON t.c501_order_id = OrderHierarchy.parent_id
)

select org_order_id,order_id from (
SELECT OrderHierarchy.org_order_id,order_id, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT(parent_id) OVER (PARTITION BY order_id) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS leaf_value
FROM OrderHierarchy
ORDER BY level) where leaf_value = 1;

END;
```

**ERROR:**

> A recursive CTE has reached the maximum number of iteration: 500

Please let me know how to resolve the issue.